# Get an latest order notes both customer and private and store in seperate custom field Woocommerce Order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I want to get an latest order notes both customer and private in two separate meta keys in the order admin console. Basically below are the things i need which i can put in functions.php

1. Add two customer fields one for private note and customer note. This can be custom field (meta_key) for order page.
2. This two custom field can be displayed  in the right side on the admin order page as metabox on right hand side
3. These two custom field will contain only the last order note (private or customer) and value will be stored in the meta_value of the key for orders.

Please help i want to use these meta_keys as variables to send the SMS.

Regards
Vishal Sanghi

Comment: Please help very urgent

Comment: Please help very urgent